# skcuda.linalg.PCA's fit_transform throws error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gpu, pca

I am trying to run PCA (Principal component analysis) on GPU. I am using skcuda.linalg.PCA for that purpose, but it's not working. From their tutorial (https://scikit-cuda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/skcuda.linalg.PCA.html):

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.gpuarray as gpuarray
import numpy as np
import skcuda.linalg as linalg
from skcuda.linalg import PCA as cuPCA
pca = cuPCA(n_components=4) # map the data to 4 dimensions
X = np.random.rand(1000,100) # 1000 samples of 100-dimensional data vectors
X_gpu = gpuarray.GPUArray((1000,100), np.float64, order="F") # note that order="F" or a transpose is necessary. fit_transform requires row-major matrices, and column-major is the default
X_gpu.set(X) # copy data to gpu
T_gpu = pca.fit_transform(X_gpu) # calculate the principal components
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
cublasInternalError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-02aaf0fa19e4> in <module>
      8 X_gpu = gpuarray.GPUArray((1000,100), np.float64, order="F") # note that order="F" or a transpose is necessary. fit_transform requires row-major matrices, and column-major is the default
      9 X_gpu.set(X) # copy data to gpu
---> 10 T_gpu = pca.fit_transform(X_gpu)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skcuda/linalg.py in fit_transform(self, X_gpu)
    204                     cuGemv (self.h, 'n', p, k, -1.0, P_gpu.gpudata, p, U_gpu.gpudata, 1, 1.0, P_gpu[:,k].gpudata, 1)
    205 
--> 206                 l2 = cuNrm2(self.h, p, P_gpu[:,k].gpudata, 1)
    207                 cuScal(self.h, p, 1.0/l2, P_gpu[:,k].gpudata, 1)
    208                 cuGemv(self.h, 'n', n, p, 1.0, R_gpu.gpudata, n, P_gpu[:,k].gpudata, 1, 0.0, T_gpu[:,k].gpudata, 1)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skcuda/cublas.py in cublasDnrm2(handle, n, x, incx)
   1295                                        n, int(x), incx,
   1296                                        ctypes.byref(result))
-> 1297     cublasCheckStatus(status)
   1298     return np.float64(result.value)
   1299 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skcuda/cublas.py in cublasCheckStatus(status)
    177             raise cublasError
    178         else:
--> 179             raise e
    180 
    181 # Helper functions:

cublasInternalError
```

Initially, I was running on my own data and I got this error. Then I decided to run the example and I got exactly the same error. Does any1 know what's the problem here? I am using Kaggle notebook with Tesla T4 GPU. Thanks.

Comment: Very urgent.. :)

Comment: I have never faced any issue with cuml pca gpu implementation and I think it's pre-installed on kaggle notebooks, https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuml/stable/api.html#principal-component-analysis

Comment: So use rapidsai PCA instead of skcuda?

Comment: Also we have: 1) from cuml import PCA
2)from cuml.decomposition import PCA. What is the difference and which one to use?

Comment: Yeah Just use rapidsai PCA

Comment: Both are same. There's no difference

Comment: Running it. Let's see if it works! :)

Comment: If it works, I will let you know so you can post this as an answer and I will accept it! :)

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. MemoryError: std::bad_alloc: CUDA error at: ../include/rmm/mr/device/cuda_memory_resource.hpp:68: cudaErrorMemoryAllocation out of memory

Comment: Is your dataset cudf dataframe or numpy array?

Comment: It is a numpy array, why?

Comment: It has dimension: (397, 30000)

Comment: If the dataset was cudf dataframe it operates on gpu memory.

Comment: Hmm. It is not. But I would like to make it to operate on gpu as well. Can I do it somehow else instead of creating a df? Like making a cufg array out of numpy array?

Comment: Or how can I make a cudf df out of numpy array?

Comment: I don't think cudf df is also not ideal in this case cause it's running out of gpu memory regardless. If you can try to use feature selection to reduce n-features (30k) you have. Or Try to convert the numpy from float32 to float16 if precision doesn't matter that much and see if that helps.

Comment: Okay, let me try.

Comment: If I have 30K very long texts (around 20K each), what number of n_features do you think is appropriate to train an algorithm?

Comment: Do you mean 30k  words per sentence?

Comment: You could give work embeddings a try, you can minimize the dimension of each text to N DIM (depends on vector used)